# Is there an HTML and/or CSS equivalent of the nroff / troff concept of a "floating display?"

Tags: html, css, troff

Is there an HTML and/or CSS equivalent of the *nroff* / *troff* concept of a
"**floating** display*?"

Note that giving an HTML element a `style` attribute with a value of
`page-break-inside:avoid` emulates an *nroff* / *troff* "**static** display*,"
**not** a "**floating** display."

(*) Here are descriptions of *nroff* / *troff* "static display" and
"floating display" from Gehani, *Document Formatting and Typesetting on
the UNIX System*, Vol. 1, p. 48:

> ...  A *static* display ensures its contents have the same relative
>   position in the formatted document as in the raw document.  If the
>   displayed material cannot fit on the current page, then rest of the
>   current page left blank and the displayed material is printed on the
>   next page.
>
> A *floating* display does not guarantee that the displayed material
>   will have the same relative position in the formatted document as it
>   had in the raw document.  If a floating display cannot fit on the
>   current page, then it is printed as soon as possible after the top of
>   the page.  However, the remainder of the current page is not left
>   blank; it is filled with items that follow the floating display in the
>   raw document.  The relative position between two floating display is
>   always preserved.  Of course, there may be several floating displays
>   waiting to be printed a the next page change; if they all cannot fit
>   there, then the remaining ones will flow onto the following page, and
>   so on.

Comment: Can you provide us with a scenario you're trying to implement?

Comment: A use case I have in mind is a technical paper with a main text and a number of figures and/or tables.

Comment: No because HTML is about document markup and not layout

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, as it would require changing the source order on the fly. If you can know for sure the paper size and the content is static, I imagine it would be more or less possible to <s>achieve</s> *simulate it* with flexbox/grid, but it would be hacky and in my opinion, defeat the purpose.

Comment: And that would be css not html